# Skip a particular package for update and proceed for all others

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

I am trying to update a production server after some months maybe. While updating the apt cache I get the following message.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                          
Ign:5 http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  InRelease
Hit:6 http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release
Get:7 http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release.gpg [481 B]
Ign:7 http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done 
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: GPG error: http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 47AE7F72479BC94B
E: The repository 'http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I see that one of the package from `ownloud` could not be verified. I want to skip updating this package for now and move to update others.

**Question:**

1. Should I just move forward with `sudo apt upgrade` for upgrading all others ?
2. How to resolve the issue with a package whose public key cannot be verified for following cases :

*(i)* *I trust the package and want to upgrade ?*

*(ii) I do not want to upgrade this package ever ?*   (I will deal with this in the
    future though) .

Comment: Maybe you can remove its source and run a `sudo apt update`

Comment: for *(i)* you want [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](//askubuntu.com/q/13065) for *(ii)* remove the repository: [How can PPAs be removed?](//askubuntu.com/q/307)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all, especially on production servers, you must have only source lists you really need. Everything else must be removed. 
Then, every source list you have should provide `trusted` packages, and the way to check that is easy - every provided package is signed by the one who provides it. Your system has keys which can verify the package signature. Those keys can be viewed with `apt-key list`. You lack a key for `http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04`. I saw that `Owncloud`'s key has expired few months ago and they have released a new one. You can obtain it from `http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key`. Download it `wget ...` and import it with `apt-key add <filename>`. Run `apt-get update` to refresh your cache.

Next - you're asking how to mask a package from being updated. This can be done with `sudo apt-mark hold package_name`. Hope that helps you.